# Set expand/collapse background images on headers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to set a different background image for collapsed and expanded headers on an accordion. Please provide assistance on how I can accomplish this.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('ul#accordion a.heading').click(function() {

        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {          
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('normal',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
            });
        } else {
            $('ul#accordion li.current ul').slideUp('normal',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
            });
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('normal',function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
            });

        }
        return false;
    }); });
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="accordion">

     <li id="AR" class="current">
       <a href="#" class="heading">ALL RESOURCES</a>
         <ul>resource options</ul>
     </li>


     <li id="BU">
       <a href="#" class="heading">BUREAUS</a>
         <ul>bureaus options</ul>
     </li>

     <li id="BN">
        <a href="#" class="heading">BUSINESS NEEDS</a>
          <ul>business options</ul>
     </li>

</ul><!-- END ACCORDION -->
```

CSS:

```
ul#accordion li a.heading { background-color: blue; }
ul#accordion li a.headingactive { background-color:red; }
```

I know that my Accordion only covers the click function of the header but I was wondering if I can also incorporate the ready function. So whichever heading is expanded, it will receive the class "headingactive".

Comment: Not really clear on what you're asking. When should the heading of the `headingactive` class? If it's at the same each `li` element gets the `current` class, you really don't need a new class since you can style with the selector `ul#accordion li.current a.heading` (to be overly specific).

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I just realized the same thing after a night of thinking. I'm still in the learning process, this is exactly what I tried and it worked. I was looking too deep into it.

Comment: Posted the same thing as answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's at the same each li element gets the current class, you really don't need a new class since you can style with the selector ul#accordion li.current a.heading (to be overly specific).